# python asyncio how to listen ipv4 and ipv6 by using one socket

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I want to listen ipv4 and ipv6 in a socket with `asyncio.start_server` in python, now I give a tuple to this function but actually it uses 2 socket to listen.

My friend tells me listen '::' can listen ipv4 and ipv6 in a socket with C language, How should I do with python asyncio

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #logging.info('start holosocket local')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='holosocket local')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', help='config file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.config:
        with open(args.config, 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)

    SERVER = config['server']
    SERVER_PORT = config['server_port']
    PORT = config['local_port']
    KEY = config['password']
    AUTH = config['auth_addr']

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    relay_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = asyncio.start_server(handle, (SERVER, '::'), SERVER_PORT, loop=loop)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux you need to disable `IPV6_V6ONLY` option. However, dual stack is by default enabled in a kernel, [asyncio disables it explicitly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1031) if you don't provide your own socket. So you need to create ipv6 socket and pass it instead of `host, port`.

```
import asyncio
import os
import socket


async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

    print("Send: %r" % message)
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('::', 7777))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, sock=sock, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

A simple test also shows a caveat with ipv4 address, prefixed `::ffff:`.

```
$ python3 test_server.py 
Serving on ('::', 7777, 0, 0)
Received 'A\r\n' from ('::1', 59954, 0, 0)
Send: 'A\r\n'
Close the client socket
Received 'B\r\n' from ('::1', 59956, 0, 0)
Send: 'B\r\n'
Close the client socket
Received 'C\r\n' from ('::ffff:127.0.0.1', 35800, 0, 0)
Send: 'C\r\n'
Close the client socket
```

More info you can find at wikipedia - [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses).

Comment: If I don't set sock=sock, it will use asyncio's version sock instead of custom sock and I am afraid of our custom sock has some difference between with asyncio's version

Comment: I've edited the answer a bit. Under the hood asyncio use the regular `socket`, more over if you want custom (from asyncio point of view) behaviour you must provide custom socket.

Comment: I edited your answer to add reuseaddr and test on my vps, it listens dual stack and works well. Thanks for your help.